# List all months from date until another date

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have two dynamic dates:

"A5" - 2018-12-01
"B5" - 2019-04-31

I would like something that would help me list all the months along with their specific years that are between both those dates (including both of them).

The output would be:

```
December 2018
January 2019
February 2019
March 2019
April 2019
```

I need to do this without a Script. These dates difference are never going to be bigger than 2 years.

Is there a way to do this that you know of? I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(UNIQUE(EOMONTH(ROW(INDIRECT(
 DATEVALUE(A5)&":"&DATEVALUE(B5))), 0)), "mmmm yyyy"))
```

[image: 0]

**note:** 2019-04-31 is not a valid date

Answer (score 0):

```
Date(year(B5),month(B5),1)
Date(year(B5),month(B5)-1,1)
Date(year(B5),month(B5)-2,1)
```

I repeated this formula only changing the month part, which gives a date list. Then, with a helper column, I used, `if(thenewcells>=date(year(A5),month(A5),1,"include","")`
This lets me know which ones to include.

However, I need to create these in advance, not dynamic